# Django : Formset as form field

Tags: django, dynamic, django-forms

one of the forms I need is a composite of simple fields (say "Department", "Building" and "RoomNumber"), and of dynamically generated pairs of fields (say "Name" and "Email"). Ideally, editing the contents of the simple fields and adding/removing dynamic field pairs would be done on a single form.

Code-wise, I'm wondering if trying to embed a Formset (of a form with the two dynamic fields) as a field in an ordinary form is a sensible approach or if there's another best practice to achieve what I'd like to accomplish.

Many thanks for any advice on these matters,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure where the idea that you need to "embed a Formset as a field" comes from; this sounds like a case for the [standard usage of formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

For example (making a whole host of assumptions about your models):

```python
class OfficeForm(forms.Form):
  department = forms.ModelChoiceField(...
  room_number = forms.IntegerField(...

class StaffForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=...
  email = forms.EmailField(...

from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

StaffFormSet = formset_factory(StaffForm)
```

And then, for your view:

```python
def add_office(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OfficeForm(request.POST)
        formset = StaffFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() && formset.is_valid():
            # process form data
            # redirect to success page
    else:
        form = OfficeForm()
        formset = StaffFormSet()

    # render the form template with `form` and `formset` in the context dict
```

Possible improvements:

- Use the [django-dynamic-formset jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) to get the probably-desired "add an arbitrary number of staff to an office" functionality without showing users a stack of blank forms every time.
- Use [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) instead (assuming the information you're collecting is backed by Django models), so you don't have to explicitly specify the field names or types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was mislead by the fact that I thought (who knows why), that it would be more practical if the `StaffFormSet` was somehow declared as a field of the `OfficeForm`. I'll give your approach a try.

Comment: I also mistakenly thought the formset should be a field on the form, but this answer helped. To add to the answer, in your template, you will render `form` and `formset` inside the same HTML `form` tag. That way all of the form data comes back in the same POST.